# Does a Myr Welder token created with Mimic Vat retain abilities added to the original?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I play [Myr Welder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMyr%20Welder%5d), then later I play [Grindclock](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrindclock%5d) (or any artifact) and it gets countered or destroyed. Next turn I exile grindclock from my graveyard with Myr Welder's activated ability and play [Mimic Vat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMimic%20Vat%5d). Myr Welder dies on the opponent's next turn and is exiled with Mimic Vat's imprint ability. Then on my next turn I activate the Vat and put a token copy of Myr Welder into play.

Does the token have Grindclock's abilities after Myr Welder had been exiled? Since the myr hit the graveyard first, I know it loses counters. But does the Grindclock remain "exiled with (Myr Welder)" allowing the use of its abilities?

Comment: This seems like something like it might have been asked before, although I can't find a really clear preexisting version. [This one is close](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23257/if-soulflayer-is-returned-to-play-from-your-graveyard-does-it-retain-abilities), as [is this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12574/when-do-copied-abilities-on-a-creature-go-away).

Comment: @David Z, Both of those have 400.7 as an answer, but the direct reason the Grindclock isn't considered exiled by the Myr Welder token has nothing to do with zone changes. The OP could equivalently have asked about a Myr Welder clone created by Clone, for example, a scenario in which no zone changes occur.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I know, that's why I didn't vote to mark as a duplicate of either of those. I didn't find a question dealing with the relation between (token) copies of something and the original thing.

Comment: Well, you said the two linked answer were close, yet they don't mention 201.4 at all.

Comment: 400.7 also applies here since myr welder hits the graveyard.

Comment: A hundred different rules "apply" in the scenario you presented. I didn't say 400.7 doesn't apply; I said it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

When an object refers to itself by name, it refers specifically to that object (regardless of its name). It does not refer to other objects with the same name.

The Myr Welder card in exile never exiled anything.

The Myr Welder token on the battlefield never exiled anything.

> 201.4. Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.

Comment: 400.7 also applies since myr welder must go to the graveyard first.

Comment: Sure, a hundred different rules "apply" in the scenario you presented, including 400.7. However, the answer to your question has nothing to do with 400.7.

Comment: Indeed. Just wanted to make sure that it it's clearly stated for any who comes looking